# Is it possible to programmatically draw GreasePencil strokes?

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I am toying with the idea of using MediaPipe for hand tracking and use that for drawing GreasePencil strokes.

The hand-tracking part is quite well documented, but how would I then relate that to positions on the screen?

And now that I think of it, it could probably lend itself to other cases as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know anything about your hand tracking system inputs. But few basic guidance below about grease pencil object creation.

```
import bpy

name='hand track'

# Create a new gp data, 
# link it to an object 
# and link the object to the scene
hand_track = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new(name)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, hand_track)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)

# Create a new layer, 
# new frame 
# and new stroke
layer = hand_track.layers.new(name)
frame = layer.frames.new(0)
stroke = frame.strokes.new()

# Simulate capture of 10 hand positions 
for i in range(10):
    # get the index of the point we'll add below (index of the last)
    index = len(stroke.points)
    # Add a stroke point
    stroke.points.add(1)
    # Set it to the wanted position
    stroke.points[index].co = (i, 0, 0)

# Set the object as selected, active and update the scene
obj.select_set(True)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
```

(A lot) more details [in the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.GPencilStroke.html).