# Updating screen upon adding a Grease Pencil point

Tags: python, grease-pencil

I am trying to see if hand tracking with [mediapipe](https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/solutions/vision/hand_landmarker) can be used to draw on screen with Grease Pencil.

I've managed a rough set up to track hands and add points accordingly thanks to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/308176/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-draw-greasepencil-strokes) but lines on screen only get updated when I select the line I've drawn, not before.

How can I ensure that screen gets redrawn every time a point is added and not just at the end?

Extremely poorly written code below - at this point it's a hack, does not take into account screen width, camera width, a ton of other things, and probably loops need to be optimized. I'm trying to see if this is a good idea at all, before I clean up.

```
import bpy
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 30)

    # New for finger detection
mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()
mpDraw = mp.solutions.drawing_utils


name='hand track'
hand_track = bpy.data.grease_pencils.new(name)
obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, hand_track)
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)

# Create a new layer, 
# new frame 
# and new stroke
layer = hand_track.layers.new(name)
frame = layer.frames.new(0)
stroke = frame.strokes.new()

class ModalTimerOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator which runs its self from a timer"""
    bl_idname = "wm.modal_timer_operator"
    bl_label = "Modal Timer Operator"

    _timer = None

    def modal(self, context, event):
        
        if event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            print("cancelled")
            bpy.context.view_layer.update()
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        if event.type == 'TIMER':
            print("5 seconds have passed")
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            # New for finger detection
            handsFrame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            results = hands.process(handsFrame)

            if results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                for handLMS in results.multi_hand_landmarks:
                    lmList = []
                    for id, lm in enumerate(handLMS.landmark):
                        h, w, c = handsFrame.shape
                        cx, cy = int(lm.x * w), int(lm.y * h)
                        lmList.append([id, cx, cy])
                    for lms in lmList:
                        if lms[0] == 7:
                            indexX, indexY = lms[1] / 400, lms[2] / 800
                            index = len(stroke.points)
                            # Add a stroke point
                            stroke.points.add(1)
                            # Set it to the wanted position
                            stroke.points[index].co = (indexX, indexY, 0)
                            print(lms)
                            
                            context.area.tag_redraw()




        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        self._timer = wm.event_timer_add(0.3, window=context.window)
        wm.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(ModalTimerOperator)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(ModalTimerOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.modal_timer_operator()
```